# MySQL DB not updating from Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

I have a program that inserts values into a table in a local database. It works fine, but when I check the DB, it isn't updated. The program even outputs the correct values. Did I connect to the database wrongly at

```
connect = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySQL://localhost/test", "root", "");
```

Any idea why?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

//static because when creating an object of it in main, you won't have to make an object of the outer class (SQLProject) first
public class MySQLAccess{
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public void readDatabase() throws Exception
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySQL://localhost/test", "root", "");

            statement = connect.createStatement();
            System.out.println("here1");
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from test.comments");
            writeResultSet(resultSet);



            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.comments values(default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            //columsn in test.comments
            // myuser, email, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "TestEmail");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "TestWebpage");
            preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(2009, 12, 11));
            preparedStatement.setString(5, "Test Summary");
            preparedStatement.setString(6, "Test Comment");
            System.out.println("here2");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT myuser, webpage, datum, summary, comments FROM test.comments");
            System.out.println("here3");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            writeResultSet(resultSet);

            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM test.comments WHERE myuser=?;");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.comments;");
            System.out.println("Writing meta data");
            writeMetaData(resultSet);
            connect.setAutoCommit(false);
            connect.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
        finally{ 

            close();
            System.out.println("ALMOST");
            }
        System.out.println("AT THE END");
    }

    private void writeMetaData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
    {
        System.out.println("The columns in the table are: ");
        System.out.println("Table: " + resultSet.getMetaData().getTableName(1));

        for(int i=1;i<=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Column " + i + " " + resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
        }
    }

    private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
    {
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            String user = resultSet.getString("myuser");
            String website = resultSet.getString("webpage");
            String summary = resultSet.getString("summary");
            Date date = resultSet.getDate("datum");
            String comment = resultSet.getString("comments");

            System.out.println("User: " + user);
            System.out.println("website: " + website);
            System.out.println("summary: " + summary);
            System.out.println("date: " + date);
            System.out.println("comment: " + comment);
        }
    }

    private void close()
    {
        try{
            if(resultSet != null)
                resultSet.close();
            if(statement != null)
                statement.close();
            if(connect != null)
                connect.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}//private inner class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect.setAutoCommit(false);`

should come immediately after connection is initialized

`connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySQL://localhost/test", "root", "");
 connect.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: please note that you are inserting , reading it again, and then deleting the comment row inserted. So db wont have the new row created on transaction commit

Comment: What if otherwise? auto commit needs to be handled explicitly only in some specific situations such as last inserted id is required to fetch (as an example). Otherwise, it's very well handled implicitly by the system.

Comment: Remove following and see the database.                           preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM test.comments WHERE myuser=?;");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Comment: @Lion yes autocommit is set false to make sure the code block between autoCommit(false) and connection.commit() is transactional